# Difference between HAVING and WHERE

Tags: mysql, database, select, where-clause

I have this table,

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     Age varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO Person
(name, Age)
VALUES
('Ganesan', '23'),
('Prasanna', '30'),
('Karthikeyan', '27'),
('RParthiban', '33');
```

And this query:

```
select Name, Age from Person HAVING Age > 30;

select Name, Age from Person WHERE Age > 30;
```

Both queries produces the same output:

```
NAME    AGE
RParthiban  33
```

Why ? Whats the difference or significance between using `Having` and `Where` ?

I am sure that there must be any. Any examples for each ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read documentation first?

Comment: @SonerGönül Why read the documentation when you can type out a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Which it takes probably 30 seconds to search it `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search about this question, you will get the answer. Here is one of them

> HAVING can be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used in a GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.

[Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/)

Answer (score 2):

A `HAVING` clause is equivalent to a `WHERE` clause for a group or aggregate.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

The syntax is `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER BY`

e.g.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(whatever) AS [Total]
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(whatever) > 100000.00
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` is for filtering query results based on condition.

`HAVING` is for applying a filter on results of an aggregate function. In absence of aggregate function it functions same as WHERE.